# Подключение к сетям в Ubuntu

Tags: сеть, wifi, ubuntu

Здравствуйте! 
Имеется ноутбук `HP Pavillion dv5`.

1. При установке `Ubuntu 12.10` не нашлась сеть ни проводная (никак не воспринялся подключенный кабель), ни `wi-fi`.
2. При установке `Ubuntu 12.04` проводная сеть также не нашлась, но к `wi-fi` подключилась. После дня успешной работы и обновления, снова ни одну сеть найти не удалось. Причем домашняя `wi-fi` сеть не видна, но видна соседская.

Устанавливала и через `wubi` и через загрузочную флешку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки стабильно подключиться к сети?

**UPD: sudo lshw -class network**

```
*-network                      description: Wireless interface       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY       vendor: Broadcom Corporation       physical id: 0       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0       logical name: eth2       version: 01       serial: 00:21:00:71:b2:96       width: 64 bits       clock: 33MHz       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg       resources: irq:16 memory:9e200000-9e203fff  *-network DISABLED       description: Ethernet interface       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.       physical id: 0       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0       logical name: eth0       version: 02       size: 10Mbit/s       capacity: 1Gbit/s       width: 64 bits       clock: 33MHz       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s       resources: irq:48 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:94010000-94010fff memory:94000000-9400ffff memory:94020000-9402ffff
```

Comment: Почитайте эту статью. [Тут][1] все детально расписано как настроить. [1]: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, вывод sudo lspci -v

Comment: @PocketSam, добавила в вопрос

Comment: @Iranda, я отредактировал свой ответ. Прочтите, пожалуйста, его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Iranda](/users/1155/iranda)](/users/1155/iranda), добавьте, пожалуйста, вывод dmesg | grep b43

После этого можете сразу попробовать следующие команды.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-sourcesudo apt-get install b43-fwcuttersudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

А после этого перезагрузиться.Это все для беспроводной сети. Сейчас мне пора бежать. Остальное посмотрим позже. :)

Так же говорят, что проблема исчезает с установкой ядра выше 3.1 rc3.Опять же, скачать все необходимые пакеты можете на другом ПК с помощью этого скрипта: http://paste.org.ru/?as3sru

Можете использовать его и для загрузки пакетов выше.python grabpackages.py -o downloader_script b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что не могу я ничего устанавливать. Проводной сети также нет.  Спасибо.

Comment: @Iranda, попробуйте для начала выполнить первую команду - это удаление. А загрузить необходимые пакеты со всеми зависимостями можно на другом ПК.Скрипт для этого был сделано на 12.04, но надеюсь, вам тоже подойдет. http://paste.org.ru/?imzoul

Answer (score 2):

в консоли от рута выполнить iwlist scan | grep -i "essid"видна своя сеть?

Comment: Своя сеть не видна, соседская - да

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте для начала сделать из терминала (консоли) это:

```
sudo service network-manager stopsudo service network-manager start
```

Очень возможно, что сеть и появится, у 12.04 весьма "интересные" фишки проявляются... ИМХО, ядра, начиная с 2.6.34 "недопилены" по такой весчи, как ACPI,APM и т.д.... Да и "камушки" пошли слабоватые - в эпоху версий 6.06 - 9.04 всё работало как часы на "коппермайне - мендосине", компиз вертелся на таких картюшках, о которых многие давно уж забыли. А теперь - только NVidia, Intel... 4 x iCore7 = Celeron II (Coppermain)600 на 100MHz шине :-)))

Comment: Увы, сеть не появилась

Comment: Хотя странно, но на несколько минут все же была

Answer (score 2):

В NetworkManager выберете "создать беспроводную сеть", введите её SSID, тип шифрования (если есть) и ключ, или "none", если нет шифрования. В свойствах NM выберите "беспроводные" и поставьте галочку "подключаться автоматически". Рестартуйте NM. Вы должны будете подключиться автоматически к своей сети, невзирая на то, "видит" её NM или нет...NM, возможно и "допилят", возможно и ядро успеют "допилить" когда-то, до очередного призыва "Переходите на новое железо!!! (ядро!!! ось!!!) с ещё более сырой реализацией ;-(Второй вариант - бродкомовский ядерный модуль у меня ставился с дополнительной парой опций - какие, я уже не помню, было это года два назад на другой оське (Lucid) и с другим типом карточки, возможно и у Вас похожий случай (как root давал в консоли "modprobe bcm43xx -ssb -ещё-что-убей-не-вспомню", затем "depmod -a"...). Эти опции конфигурировали карточку под питание, запрещали-разрешали promisc- и AP-конфигурации...

Comment: P.S Проверьте ещё настройки своей точки доступа - возможно она реботает в "скрытом" режиме - не рассылает beacon-пакеты...

Comment: P.P.S. Возможно и драйвер Вам нужен не bcmwl, а просто bcm(43)...